# Does there exist a polynomial function for every n points, whose extremas are these points?

Tags: functions, polynomials, systems-of-equations, curves

Given $ n $ points in $ \mathbb{R}^2 $, does there exist a polynomial function of any degree, whose extremas include these $ n $ points?

Given 3 points:
$
P_1 = (0,4), P_2 = (2,2), P_3 = (4,7)
$

And some function $f(x)$, for which the following holds:
$$
P_1, P_2, P_3 \in f(x)
\\
f'(0) = f'(2) = f'(4) = 0
$$

So $f(x)$ should be at least of degree 4 (please correct me if I'm wrong).
$$
f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^3 a_i \ x^i
\\
f'(x) = \sum_{i=1}^3 i \ a_i \ x^{i-1}
$$
That means I need to find 4 unknown variables => 4 equations.

I could use:

1. $f'(0) = 0$
2. $f'(2) = 0$
3. $f'(4) = 0$
4. $f \ (0) = 4$

And here's the problem: The $y$ coordinates of the points don't matter. So is it possible to find such a polynomial function? If it is, how do I find it?

#### Why I need this function:

I would like to write a generator for 3D objects with organic shapes. I would like to use a mathematical function to describe the shape of the object. Ideally a user should be able to define points, the extremas, and the program generates a shape that doesn't exceed these points.

Comment: Why is $f'(2)=2$ and $f'(4)=7$ not appearing in your list of equations? Also, [Hermite Interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_interpolation) might be something you want to look into.

Comment: Does $P_1 = (0/4)$ mean $P_1 = (0, 4)$?

Comment: @Wrzlprfmt because I just need 4 equations for 4 unkown variables, don't I?

Comment: @JasonZimba yes, sorry for the unclear notation!

Comment: @le_me: Well, if I understand your goal correctly, you have 6 equations to fulfill. Hence you need 6 variables (unless you are lucky). (Or with other words: degree 4 is wrong.)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft is right. You should have $n$ equations for derivatives and $n$ equations for values. So use a degree $2n-1$ polynomial. In your example, you'll get $f(x)=-\frac{9}{128}x^5+\frac{31}{64}x^4-\frac{19}{32}x^3-\frac{11}{16}x^2+4$: http://i.stack.imgur.com/qWEBd.png

Comment: that's awesome, thank you guys!! You really helped me to understand systems of equations better (I'm a student)! I guess that's the answer to my question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is a special case of the [Hermite Interpolation Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_interpolation), where you are looking for a polynome $P$ whose derivatives up to order $m-1$ (including the 0-th derivative, i.e., the value of the polynome itself) match given values in some points $x_1, \ldots,x_n$.

In your case $m$ is 2 and the given values for the derivative are always 0. For given set of $m \cdot n$ conditions, there is exactly one polynome of degree $n\cdot m -1$ or lower that fulfills your conditions, so in your case you will need a polynome of degree $2n-1$ for $n$ points. (This polynome may incidentally have a lower degree.) In particular, this means that your polynome may have additional local extrema in the relevant domain, which may even be more “extreme” than your prescribed extrema.

Considering your application you might want to take a look at other interpolation functions than polynomes such as Bézier curves, [splines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_%28mathematics%29) or [spiros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_spiral), which are all used by vector graphic programs, the first ones being by far the most common¹. Given the right constraints, these are more likely to fulfill your criteria.

---

¹ Also, you might want to take a general look at some vector graphic programs such as Inkscape, since your application with the user defining some points and the program generating an appropriate curve from this is roughly what these programs do.

Comment: thank you for this detailed answer and the suggestions regarding my application of polynomial functions.

I was able to write a program to find the polynomial function with extremas at given points and experienced the problem you're describing here: there are additional extremas in the relevant domain.

Hopefully Bézier curves will work better than polynomial functions, however, I consider it as a great success that it's possible to generate [actual objects](http://i60.tinypic.com/15hoks4.jpg) with polynomial functions.

Comment: I would upvote your answer but I can't as I don't have 15 reputation yet. I'm sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little unclear as to the exact conditions you require the polynomial to satisfy, so I'm going to answer the question in the title. Given points $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$, to make a polynomial which has extrema at those points first form the polynomial
$$
P(x)=(x-x_1)(x-x_2)\cdots(x-x_n).
$$
Now let $Q(x)$ be the integral of $P(x)$, say $Q(x)=\int_0^x P(t)\,dt$. The polynomial $Q(x)$ has extrema at the points $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$, as desired.

Comment: thanks, I'm going to check this out!

Comment: That would only give you extrema at $x_1=0, x_2=2$ and $x_3=4$, but you would not get $P(0)=4, P(2)=2)$ and $P(3)=7$.

Comment: "I'm a little unclear as to the exact conditions you require the polynomial to satisfy, so I'm going to answer the question in the title." Okay. You could make at least one of the equations hold (say $P(0)=4$) by adding the right constant to the polynomial, which wouldn't change the extrema. Past that, I'm not sure.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft is right, that doesn't give me extremas at the actual points, instead just at the x coordinates of the points.

Comment: I see what you mean. I think I misunderstood your original question. I constructed a function which has extrema at the $x$-values of the points you gave, but doesn't necessarily have the right $y$-values.

Comment: @le_me In any case, if you're interested in making organic objects you may have better luck with some sort of [fractal art](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_art). I don't think a polynomial function would be good for this sort of thing: you may run into a problem with [Runge's phenomenon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon), for example.

Comment: thanks for your help, I'm going to dive into fractals after my polynomial function experiment!

Comment: [Here's a pic](http://i60.tinypic.com/15hoks4.jpg) of one of my results ;)